# If $A \cdot x \leq b$, what values should A and B take so that $2<[x1,x2]<20$

Tags: inequality

$A$ is a `2x2` Matrix, $b$ is a `2x1`collumn vector, and $x$ is a `1x2` row vector.

I've been trying to figure this out for a while, but I cant get my head around it.

Comment: @naslundx question has been edited to clarify what I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rearrange the inequality to get:

$$[2,2]^T < x \leq A^{-1}b < [20,20]^T$$

Let $C=A^{-1}b = [c_1,c_2]^T$. Then we require that $2 < c_1 < 20$ and $2 < c_2 < 20$. Thus we get a system of linear inequalities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is a matrix equation. For simplicity I just simplified it by assuming A, x and b are real scalar numbers. I thought this would help me understand. In the real equation A is a `2x2` matrix, b is a `2*1` row vector, and x is a `1x2`vector.  I'm still a bit confused though. I want `2<x<20` (for both x's), so would I use `A = [1,1;1,1], b = [20;2]`?

Comment: In that case we get $[2;2] < A^{-1}b < [20;20]$.

Comment: Sorry this is a bad question. I'm going to edit it, so it is clear what I need to know.

Comment: @Blue7 I have edited the contents to suit matrices. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks. I think so... I've never seen matrix inequality's before so this is all quite difficult. In this case would `A= [1 1;-1 -1]`, and `b = [20;2]` have the same effect as `2<[x1,x2]<20`?

Comment: Actually `b` should be `b=[20;-2]`